# Присяжные — от слова "приседать"?

Tags: этимология

Члены суда — присяжные. А откуда такое название? Это от слова "приседать", что ли?)))
Заранее спасибо за разъяснения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

От "присяги". Присягу приносят (или принимают - тут тоже спорят) перед тем как приступить к выполнению своих обязанностей в качестве заседателей.
Исторически такое название выбрано потому, что в судах "заседают" не только те, кто приносил присягу. А у "присяжных заседателей" после присяги появляются вполне определенные права и обязанности. Аналогично - "присяжный поверенный" (особая должность в судах Российской Империи) и проч.

Сейчас смысл выражений несколько выветрился, осталось только "присяжные" - члены суда присяжных. "Заседатели" исчезло из активного употребления.

Answer (score 5):

От слова "присягать". Присягают они судить честно и беспристрастно.

Answer (score 5):

В слове *присяга* (клятва) мы находим корень **сяг**, который означает прикосновение : *досягать*, *недосягаемый*, *посягать на честь*...
Присяга производилась на Библии или других священных книгах, в наше время президенты и должностные лица присягают на Конституции. Военнослужащие целуют знамя. Прикосновение к святыне символизирует нерушимость клятвы.
Привести к присяге, заставить присягнуть - серьезная процедура, она связана с верой и общим нравственным чувством человека.

Comment: Однокоренное слово, надо упомянуть : *осязание*.

Comment: >Однокоренное слово, надо упомянуть : осязание.  
  
Ой ли?  А что тогда такое Г в "присяге"? Что-то не знаю я подобных суффиксов... Есть суффикс "яг": бродить - бродяга с другим значением, кстати, но что тогда остаётся корню?

Comment: **Сяг/сяз** - это корень слов досягать/осязать. Дотронуться, прикоснуться. О суффиксах тут речи не идет. 
>Сяжу, сязаю, сягну , малоупотр. Хватаю, или достаю, касаюсь до чего. (САР 1789)

Comment: >сязаю, сягну , малоупотр. Хватаю, или достаю, касаюсь до чего

Есть такое слово! Употребляется на Украине (не очень широко употребляется и не во всех областях, но вполне литературное слово). 

*Сягаю, сягну*. Инфинитив -- *сягнути*.

Например, *"сягнути зiрок"* -- достать до звёзд.

Не думал, что "присяга" связано с "сягну". Но возможно и так. Интересная версия, +1. На Украине "присяга" -- значит "клятва". "Я присягаюся" -- я клянусь.